# Can duct sealant be used around PVC

Tags: ducts, pvc

I have a leaky spot on my ductwork surrounded by PVC exhaust pipes and it's a hard spot to reach so it would be difficult for me to put duct sealant on it without getting it splashed onto the PVC pipe.

Is duct sealant safe around PVC, i.e. will it not affect the structural integrity of PVC pipe over the long term?

I was contemplating water based duct sealant like the following:

[DP-1010](https://www.generalinsulation.com/products/hvac/sealants-adhesives/design-polymerics-dp1010-water-based-duct-sealant/)

or the one they sell at home depot, master flow

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Master-Flow-Water-Based-Mastic-0-91-Gal-Tub-WBA100/301784793

Comment: Take a look at the info on the can or tube.  Usually tells you what the product can and cannot be used with/for.

Comment: Check the label or contact the manufacturer. Might well vary between types of duct sealant, and you have not specified one. You could protect the PVC pipes with something like aluminum foil, too.

Comment: updated with some examples of water-based duct sealant

Comment: "Ground Limestone" "Fullers Earth" "water based" "mastic" https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/3d/3dd28b1f-9700-4f39-afb3-2d0639ba0db1.pdf - I don't see why not. It's mastic with ground stone which is basically clay, actual clay, and fibers to make it more viscous. If it was oil based, maybe, but not really; PVC is one of the more benign materials and why we use it for pipe. Just don't set it on fire.

Comment: Just don't get it on anything you don't want it on because that shit don't come off. Meaning: you're supposed to use tape on the machine and its coil otherwise you basically have to destroy everything to swap it out. It's kinda like coating everything in liquid nails which at that point you're SoL.

Comment: Other than causing headaches down the line, I can't think of anything this would be bad to get it on. But I've always wondered... *WTF is in this anyway? Isn't it just crappy paint?* +1